# Reasoning behind "If a VLQ answer is old, it probably doesn't benefit from commentary."

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, low-quality-posts

When I'm reviewing the [LQP queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), and I click <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> on an old answer, the popup has limited options, and there's a text at the bottom, saying:

> This answer has been on the site for quite a while now; it probably won't benefit from commentary.

[image: Screenshot]

I found that strange:

- Why is commentary less probable than other VLQ-reasons (e.g. *link-only*-ness) on an old answer?
- I've seen some old commentary answers in the LQP queue.
- Why is the removal of options good, even if those options are improbable?

**My question is:**

What's the reasoning behind the above statement?

Is there any statistical or logical reason of it?

Comment: For old answers it is very unlikely that the user will respond to the comment and edit the answer. You still should vote to delete where it suits, but leaving a specific comment is not needed.

Comment: @yivi I don't think that it's a duplicate as my question is about *why* is it improbable that an old answer is commentary...

Comment: Well, in the linked question the answer mentions _"for posts made by new users it might help them in getting acquainted in the ways of Stack Overflow"_. So comments are more useful for users who might be learning the ropes. Less useful for old hands. Other reasons might be than authors for very old posts may have been inactive for a while, or left the site altogether, etc.

Comment: The only purpose of these comments is to persuade the poster to go back and edit their answer. That's almost certainly not going to happen once the answer is beyond a certain age threshold. There's no other reason to post these comments. Either edit the post yourself to correct the issues, or flag it to have a moderator delete it. If you can't do the former, and don't think the latter is appropriate, then there's nothing more to do. Noisy comments don't help anyone.